# Initialize complex map in constructor with initializer list

Tags: c++, dictionary, initialization-list

I was wondering the other day whether it is possible in C++ (any standard) to initialize a map in an initializer list of a constructor with a loop or a more complex procedure than literals such that I can make it a `const` member variable?

```
class MyClass {
public:
    const int myInt;
    const std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
    MyClass(int i) : myInt(i), /* initialize map like: for(int i = 0; i < myInt; ++i) { map[i] = whatever; } { }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you can always call a (freestanding or static) function that returns a map that depends on the run-time value of `i`? You won't be able to do that with literals, or (even recursive ) constexpressions, or (even recursive) templates because `i` is not known at compile time. The problem is the overhead in passing a map by value with pre-move standards/implementations.

Comment: You can use a function or a lambda expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `lambda` function inside constructor initializer list. Like so:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    const int myInt;
    const std::unordered_map<int, int> umap;
    MyClass(int i) : myInt(i), umap( [i]() -> decltype(umap) {
      std::unordered_map<int, int> tu;
      for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        tu[j]=j;
      return tu; 
    }()) {}
};
```